# HTML & CSS: Centering the Navbar

Tags: html, css, center, navbar

I've looked up other people who have had similar problems but I can't seem to find an answer that works for me. I'm trying to center my nav bar but it keeps getting pushed off to the left. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

```css
    body {
      background-color: rgb(222, 243, 246);
      /* background-image: url("Capitola.jpg"); 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: contain;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
    */
    }
    div.image {
      background-image: url("Capitola.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 10 solid #021a40;
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    div#wrapper {
      position: fixed;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 1000;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .navbar ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-radius: 500px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .navbar li {
      float: left;
      display: inline;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .navbar a {
      display: inline-block;
      font-weight: bold;
      width: 120px;
      color: black;
      background-color: rgb(254, 255, 241)
      /*rgb(219,243,245)*/
      ;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .navbar a:hover {
      background-color: rgb(239, 162, 180);
    }
    h1 {
      font-family: Florence, cursive;
      margin-top: 8%;
      margin-left: 60%;
      color: white;
      font-size: 3.5em;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  <title>Michael Leath</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="image">
    <h1>Michael Leath</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#aboutme">About Me</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#education">Eduation</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#background">Background</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a width for the #wrapper `margin: 0 auto` to work :)

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(222, 243, 246);
  /* background-image: url("Capitola.jpg"); 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: contain;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
    */
}
div.image {
  background-image: url("Capitola.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 10 solid #021a40;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
div#wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.navbar li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 120px;
  color: black;
  background-color: rgb(254, 255, 241)
  /*rgb(219,243,245)*/
  ;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(239, 162, 180);
}
h1 {
  font-family: Florence, cursive;
  margin-top: 8%;
  margin-left: 60%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  <title>Michael Leath</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="image">
    <h1>Michael Leath</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#aboutme">About Me</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#education">Eduation</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#background">Background</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

in css file, change

> div#wrapper {
>         position: fixed;

as

> div#wrapper {
>         position: center;

it works then.